# RelativeLayout doesn't wrap_content on width on Android 6

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have 2 devices: Asus Zenfone 2 (6.0.1) and Galaxy Note 3 (5.0)
In my app I take photo and on the next screen I show it on ImageView and add some information on it. Here is xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/preview_buttons"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="@android:color/black">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="CANCEL"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_accept"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="ACCEPT"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/preview_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:layout_above="@id/preview_buttons">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_preview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/preview_top_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/image_preview"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/image_preview"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:background="@drawable/top_text_background"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/image_preview"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image_preview"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_verified_grey600"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/preview_bottom_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/image_preview"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image_preview"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_text_background"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

UPD. I have problem with RelativeLayout "preview_container"

From this layout I expect its width would wrap, if ImageView's width doesn't fill whole screen and be on the screen center. And it works nice on GN3, but on my AZ2 I get space at right side (No reputation to insert image, it's here https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZM6x.jpg)

UPD2. What I expect: RelativeLayout wraped correctly, so I don't see background. Example from my GN3 here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjgK0.jpg). Transparent background also can't help because after that I need to get drawing cache of this layout and work with it

I know about alignParent issue, but I don't use it now and my extra views placed correct.
Please help me, what's wrong?

Comment: to be more clear with your question can you put both expected image and the image you are getting

Comment: @MansiSalvi Updated, look at UPD2

Answer (score 0):

Your `preview_top_text` has the width set to `match_parent` so it means that, since her container is the same of the image, it will stretch way to contain also the textview and not only the `imageview`.

Add the `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` parameter to the `imageview` and it should be centered.

Hope it helped

**UPDATE POINT 2**

two possibilities:

- change the sizes of the `TextViews`  to `wrap_content`
- change the background of the second `relativelayout` to `transparent`

Comment: android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

Comment: @TeazMalker I don't get if that was a question

Comment: Whoops! I wanted answer, that its helped with centered, thank you, but now I have borders both left and right. Changes with preview_top_text doesn't helped

Comment: @TeazMalker that part was not in the question, that's your goal? you don't want to see the relativelayout content but only the part below? you can set the background to transparent :)

Comment: Updated, look at UPD2

Comment: Change sizes didn't help. Change background removed only color, but in fact I had this borders and it will be a part of final image (RelativeLayout drawing cache). It seems to be bug, because of different behavior on different devices :( May be I should redesign bottom buttons to overlay photo, to be sure that ImageView would fit whole screen

Comment: @TeazMalker honestly I don't get what you want. the image has to fill the full width of the screen? now it's centered and you see behind her, what is the problem? anyway.. why you have two relative layouts? you can use only one for al of this

Comment: What I decided to do: I remove bottom views (make them animated appears from bottom overlaying image), so my taken picture always fit whole screen, both width and height. That's not what I exactly wanted, but looks better, no ugly borders and image doesn't stretch. Thanks for your advices, but I'm not sure if I should accept your answer, cause it isn't fully solution. If you want, I'll do it, because it's really useful advices

Comment: @TeazMalker you don't have to if that was not a solution :) Btw just to say, the answer solver the problem in the question, if you wanted something different just explain and I will improve the answer :) I don't get what your goal was. you wanted the image in the center of the screen overlaying the below's background. so the image should appear as a "popup" and you could see the image below?

Comment: @TeazMalker a question: in your code you use the `preview_container` for something code side? because you can remove it and the result would be the same.. relative layout inside a relative layout is useless unless you need it for some specific code operations

Comment: Sorry, so busy today... Yes, I use preview_container to call getDrawingCache() of it later. That trick can give me image like screenshot, but not all screen, just my image with extra added views on it. And my problem was that I got screenshot with borders, and it is really ugly. I didn't try to call getDrawingCache() because I thought this wouldn't include added views (cause I think it different levels of layout drawing)

Comment: @TeazMalker don't worry, try those steps: change in all textviews the with from match_parent to wrap_content. 2) remove paddings right and left and also margins right and left from textviews and buttons. after those steps, where are the margins coming from? or better, which view cause them?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_preview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            />
```

**android:layout_height="match_parent"** should not be **match_parent**.

Comment: That didn't help :(